# jsoup tag extraction

Tags: java, jsoup

how can extract the tag from this html

```
<dl>
<dt>test:</dt>
    <dd id="rating" class="">+0 / -0 (0)</dd>
<dt>up:</dt>
    <dd>GMT</dd>
<dt>By:</dt>
    <dd></dd>
<dt>example:</dt>
    <dd>5</dd>
<dt>file:</dt>
    <dd>8</dd>
</dl>
```

how can i extract the 5 and 8 in this html code using jsoup....please help me

Answer (score 3):

```
doc.select("dt:contains(example) + dd")
```

Would select the dd containing "5". The complete syntax is available [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

```
doc.select("dt:contains(example) + dd").first().text()
```

Would be the 5 itself.

Comment: <h1 class="sprite_torrent torrent_icon">Pretty Little  </h1>

 Element title = doc.select("hl.sprite_torrent torrent_icon").first();
it shows error y????

Comment: "sprite_torrent" and "torrent_icon" are two separate classes. Doc.select("h1.sprite_torrent") will work, but you can't put both in there like that, just use one or the other.

Judging by the documentation, the following MAY work: Doc.select("h1.sprite_torrent.torrent_icon") but I don't know for sure.

Also, in the code you pasted you have an "l" (lowercase L) as in "hl" instead of "h1".

Comment: <div style="height:240px;"><br>Music: Pritam Chakraborty & ani <br>Lyrics: Irshad Kamil, Nitin Raikwar & Shehzad <br>Year: 2010<br> how can i extract the Misic :         i tried this but failed Elements music = doc.select("div[style=height:240px]"); this didnt work for me....

Comment: @suja, you've missed a semicolon. Try: `select("div[style=height:240px;]")`, or use a prefix match like `div[style^=height:240]`.